# How can I use machine learning modules from Azure ML Studio in Azure ML Workbench

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

So I've been using Azure ML Studio for a while and now Microsoft have come up with the new tool called Azure ML Workbench.  The workbench seems to be pretty low level and it seems that the majority of functions need to be hand coded in Python.

So if I have an experiment in Azure ML Studio using some of the drag and drop Training methods such as Matchbox and Boosted Decision Trees.  How can I convert these to run in Azure ML Workbench ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Seems like it would be a very useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ML Studio modules in Workbench, as these are separate tools with separate purposes.

Keep in mind that you don't necessarily need to hand-code the algorithms in Workbench - you're free to use libraries such as [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) to get the job done.

Alternatively, you can deploy your ML Studio model as a predictive web service and use it as such from Workbench, but I wouldn't really recommend this approach (and it doesn't sound to me that this is what you'd want, either).